# Проблема с открытием активити после поиска в listview

Tags: java, android

Cделал поиск по уроку, но проблема в открытии фрагментов(активити), после организации поиска. Допустим в списке 5 элементов если без поиска все открывается нормально, начинаешь искать меняются позиции у элементов в результате открывается не то, что надо, нельзя ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы № позиции оставался неизменным. Или вызывать может можно не по позиции, а как нибудь еще?

Код

```
public class FragmentSearch extends Fragment {

    String[] items;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(id.lst);
        editText=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(id.txtsearch);
        initList();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    // Обновление listview
                    initList();
                } else {
                    // выполнение поиска
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        //Создание нового фрагмента и транзакции
                        Fragment Stay1 = new Stay1();
                        // Замените все, что есть в представлении fragment_container, этим фрагментом,
                        //И добавьте транзакцию в задний стек
                        tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay1);
                        tr.addToBackStack(null);
                        //Завершить транзакцию
                        tr.commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:

                        //Создание нового фрагмента и транзакции
                        Fragment Stay2 = new Stay2();
                        // Замените все, что есть в представлении fragment_container, этим фрагментом,
                        //И добавьте транзакцию в задний стек
                        tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay2);
                        tr.addToBackStack(null);
                        //Завершить транзакцию
                        tr.commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            if(!item.contains(textToSearch)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    //передача результатов поиска в listview
    public void initList(){
        String [] arr1;
        arr1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stops);
       // Arrays.sort(arr1);
        items=arr1;
        listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout.list_item, id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в слушателе нажатий на список идет жесткая привязка к номеру позиции, т.е. предполагается что под 0 и 1 индексом в списке всегда будут одни и те-же значения, а после фильтрации на позициях 0 и 1 могут оказаться совсем другие надписи

Поэтому тебе нужно проверять не по номеру позиции, а по тексту позиции например

Решение:

```
public class FragmentSearch extends Fragment {

    String textPosition0;
    String textPosition1;
    ...


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                String currentPosition = listItems.get(postion);
                if (currentPosition.equals(textPosition0) {
                    Fragment Stay1 = new Stay1();
                    ...
                } else if (currentPosition.equals(textPosition0) {
                    Fragment Stay2 = new Stay2();
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    public void initList(){
        ...
        textPosition0 = listItems.get(0);
        textPosition1 = listItems.get(1);
    }
}
```